# git - rebase branch, built on top of another, on master

Tags: git, github

I am working on a feature in a repo. I have created a feature branch (say `branch_1`) and another branch (say `branch_2`) on top of `branch_1`. I used to rebase `branch_2` every time `branch_1` was updated, but now the `branch_1` is being merged into `master` so I want to rebase `branch_2` into `master`, so that `branch_2` have only its own changes. How do I do this? Also is the right way or is there any other method?

Comment: Why not merge `branch_2` to `branch_1` and then merge `branch_1` again to `master`? Branches keep going forward, so this could be done. Besides, the merge from `branch_2` is essentially a "commit" on `branch_1`; which one would want to merge to `master` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just rebase this branch on master:

```
src/myproject (branch2)$ git rebase master
```

Any changes in contains that are already in master will be "swallowed" into those master changes, and you'll remain with just the distinct changes this branch contains.

Comment: This may not go smoothly, because now `master` has a single merge commit coming from `branch_1`, whereas `branch_2` has a series of commits which are functionally similar to that merge commit.  Rebasing on `master` would mean bringing in that merge commit and then replaying the same commit changes later on in the rebase. Certainly not the history the OP would want.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite convenient to never rebase your feature branches but merge them with the upstream. However, it kind of assumes that you don't deliver your merges but only the squashed content of the branches (because who wants all those merges on master, right?).

In large systems it can be quite nice to have this uplift history preserved in your development branch, since the uplift can introduce new problems to your feature. Rebasing the feature branch can hide what introduced the problem, even though the problem is of course the same.

Say you have branches `master`, `feat1` off of `master` and `feat2` off of `feat1`.

To uplift `feat2` to a new `feat1` you do:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/feat2
git merge origin/feat1
git push origin feat2
```

Uplifting `feat1` to a new `master` would be:

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/feat1
git merge origin/master
git push origin feat1
```

But then say you want to switch upstream for `feat2` because `feat1` has been delivered to `master`. No problem.

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/feat2
git merge origin/master
git push origin feat2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions for you request. If you are not satisfied with [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394223/4754248) you can try to rebuild your branch using [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). Basically, create a new branch from `master` and pick all commits from the place where `branch_1` was merged into `master` to `HEAD` commit of `branch_2`. To do so you will have to use a command like (assuming you are on the new branch):

```
git cherry-pick branch_2~10 branch_2
```

assuming that 10 is the number of commits in `branch_2` after merging of `branch_1`. `branch_2` without specifying a number of 'commits back' is the latest commit of the branch.